# How do I use unique_ptr in this scenario?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a problem with this code:

```
A* a = createAnAObject().get();
```

where createAnAObject() returns unique_ptr

the problem is that I have to do this:

```
x.setA(a);   // Pass ownership here
```

and the `X` object must have ownership of the `A` object, however, as I understand it, `unique_ptr::get()` creates a temporary object, which goes out of scope the next line and calls the destructor, deleting my `A` object?

What should I do? I cannot change the interface to the `X` object.

I think I need to pass ownership not to a non-unique_ptr, as I cannot change the X class to have a unique_ptr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of calling `get` you can call `release`, which will give you the underlying pointer and release ownership.

```
A* a = createAnAObject().release();
```

If you have any additional code between the two calls, I'd recommend keeping the `std::unique_ptr` around until you call `setA` so that you don't have any leaks if things go wrong:

```
auto a_ptr = createAnAObject();
//...
x.setA(a_ptr.release());
```

Answer (score 2):

To add an alternative answer, `setA()` should probably take an `std::unique_ptr` by value since it is intending to claim ownership, thus the code could become:

```
auto a_ptr = createAnAObject();
//...
x.setA(std::move(a_ptr));
```

And thus no ugly `.release()` in sight.  After all, what happens if the first thing that `setA()` does is throw an exception?  Now you have a pointer escaping the protection of it being owned by something that will properly release it.

Edit: If you can't change X (and shame on them for their suboptimal implementation), then you're stuck with `.release`.

Answer (score -2):

Call release as defined here: [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) it relinquishes the ownership and is assignable to your ptr.